# Object isn't being drawn

Tags: java, android

I want to draw an image, but everytime I run my application, it crushes. It says, **"unfortunately, App Version1 has stopped."**
I have a Missile.java class, a Board.java class which is the activity, and layout_board, where I combine the Missle.java to the layout.

**Board.java:** (Imported everything)

```
public class Board extends AppCompatActivity {
    int coinsCounter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.board_layout);
        setCoinsCounter(0);

     //   setContentView(new MyView(this,null));
    }
}
```

**Missile.java:**

```
public class Missile extends ImageView {
    Paint p;

    public Missile(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        p = new Paint();
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.missile_cartoon);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, null);

    }
}
```

**board_layout.xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1.Missile
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/missile"/>


// Un-relevant things (TextViews, ImageViews, etc):
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/coinsCounter"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:src="@drawable/pause_pic"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="50dp"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
   />

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/coinPic"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:src="@drawable/coin_cartoon"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="20dp"
    android:maxWidth="45dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/coinsCounter"
 android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Log:**

```
    06-16 18:29:07.931 3311-3311/com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-16 18:29:07.942 3311-3311/com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                        Process: com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1, PID: 3311
                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1/com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1.Board}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1.Missile
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1.Missile
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                            at com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1.Board.onCreate(Board.java:18)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1.Missile
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:628)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                            at com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1.Board.onCreate(Board.java:18) 
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
                                                                                            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:528)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:492)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:592)
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                            at com.myfirstapplication.owner.appversion1.Board.onCreate(Board.java:18) 
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the crash and the message of the error. The message "unfortunately, App Version1 has stopped" is not the error message...that is just telling you the app crashed. Check your logcat and please post the output into your question.

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe edited :)

Answer (score 0):

It says here

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

Your Missile class needs to have a constructor that matches that given signature

```
public class Missile extends ImageView {
    // ...

    public Missile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
```

Personally I recommend the following pattern

```
public class Missile
        extends ImageView {
    public Missile(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public Missile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public Missile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public Missile(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    //  ...
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Can you explain to me, what's that "init"?

Comment: If you need to do anything in the constructor, I just add that to make sure you don't need to duplicate the constructor logic and that it's called no matter what constructor uses it

Comment: Ok, thanks :) If I may one more question - now it's not crushing, just not drawing it. Any help? Thanks again!

Comment: I actually don't see why it wouldn't, although I can 100% guarantee that you'll crash with an OutOfMemoryError the moment it does :P don't decode the bitmap in `onDraw()`, onDraw can be called many times